# Pass List of Strings to Java method

Tags: java, string, list, return-type

I have a question how to use this Java method [`boolean[] hasRoles(List<String> roleIdentifiers)`](https://shiro.apache.org/static/1.2.3/apidocs/org/apache/shiro/subject/Subject.html#hasRoles(java.util.List)).

How I can send it list of Strings?

Comment: Where do you use this method. If in java code then you should learn java, it will be obvious how to execute method with a list of strings.

Comment: For example I tried this `List<String> data = null; currentUser.hasRoles(data)` but I get `incompatible types: boolean[] cannot be converted to boolean`

Comment: @PeterPenzov The error message you describe in a comment is an essential part of your problem, overall changing the questions direction. It does belong to the question and should not be given in a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method returns a `boolean[]` not a `boolean` The error is complaining about how you use the result

```
List<String> data = ...;
if (currentUser.hasRoles(data)) // will not work as a boolean[] if not a boolean
```

You need to check the element of the `boolean[]`

One alternative is to check `hasAllRoles` which does return a `boolean` or check for the specific roles you are interested in by index.

Answer (score 1):

You could pass an implementation of the `List<T>` interface, for example:

```
1) instance.hasRoles(new ArrayList<String>()); // the empty list
2) instance.hasRoles(Arrays.asList("s1", "s2", ...)); // the list with values
3) instance.hasRoles(new ArrayList<String>() { // look at @Sam's comment
       {
           add(...);
           ...
       }
   });
```

Instead of `List<String> data = null;`, you should initialize your list.

It seems you are trying to do something like <strike>`boolean`</strike>`result = instance.hasRoles(...);`, but the type that returns from the method is different. `boolean` and `boolean[]` are not the same.

Comment: The `Arrays.asList()` method should always be preferred over the double-brace initialization method; `new ArrayList<String>() {{ add(...); }}` *creates a new class every time you use it*.

Comment: @Sam every time you use it in code, but once for line of code at runtime.

Comment: @PeterLawrey can you clarify? I'm not clear what you're saying.

Comment: @Sam every time you do a `{{ }}` you get one more class compiled, but not one more class each time the line of code is run. i.e. use it at runtime.